# index.io.bundle not found while using iOS simulator to run first React Native app

Tags: ios, xcode6, react-native

Following the [Getting Started](http://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html#content) documentation for `React Native`,
an HTML page with red background containing 
`<p>The requested URL /index.ios.bundle was not found on this server.</p>`
is rendered when hitting `cmd+R` to run my first app.

Why is that happening when the expected result should be a homepage rendered from `index.ios.js`?

Comment: Is the packager running? It normally pops up in a console window when you run the project in Xcode. If not, try checking that port 8081 is not already in use.

Comment: Thank you @ColinRamsay, your suggestion was correct. I could figure which program as listening to port 8081 and everything is fine now.

Comment: Great! Don't forget to mark your question as answered to help out other people with this problem!

Comment: Thank you @ColinRamsay, I'll do as you recommended in two in order to abide by stackoverflow rules.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had another program listening to port `8081` which is used from localhost to serve the bundle (`/index.ios.bundle`), hence I had to stop this program listening port `8081` in order to have `React Packager` working properly.

I could figure which program was listening using the following command:

`lsof -n -i4TCP:8081 | grep LISTEN`